# derivative of a parametric function at a point

Tags: calculus, derivatives, parametric

I need to find the derivative of
$$l\begin{cases}
y=t\cdot \cos(t)\\
x=e^t-2t-1
\end{cases}
$$
at $(0,0)$.

How do I approach this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}\bigg|_{(0,0)}=\biggl(\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}\biggr)_{t=0}$$

Therefore $\frac{dy}{dx}\bigg|_{(0,0)}=\biggr(\frac{y'(t)}{x'(t)}\biggl)_{t=0}=\biggl(\frac{cos(t)-tsin(t)}{e^t-2}\biggr)_{t=0}=-1$

Comment: How do you know that $t=0$?

Comment: Note that $x$ has zero only in the interval $(-a,a)$ for some $a$ with $0<a<\pi/2$ since $x(±\pi/2)\not =0$. And $y$ has zero only at the points $\frac{n\pi}{2},n\in \Bbb Z$.